# PHP POST for HTML Select using another POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

This ain't something not working but just I'm confusing about how to do it, I want to fetch the values from my DB based on users' preferences that been chosen earlier.
These are the steps will be taken for my process:

1. User will select from images (will add HTML images then will whip it upon another selection)
2. Will continue till reaching last stage
3. Last stage will have 3 Select (dropdown menus) and 2 of them will change the content according to what user's chooses (like country and state dd)

My PHP:

```
else if ($_POST["data_key"]=="last")
{   
    $final_arr;
    $fetcher_theme =    $_POST["themeid"];
    $fetcher_category=  $_POST["themecategory"];
    $fetcher_product=   $_POST["themeproduct"];
    $fetcher_cover =    $_POST["ctitle"];

    $myquery="SELECT DISTINCT Layout.* FROM Layout,Products,Occasion, Cover, Theme 
    WHERE Layout.product=$fetcher_product 
    AND Layout.occasion=$fetcher_category 
    AND Layout.theme=$fetcher_theme 
    AND Layout.cover=$fetcher_cover;";


    $results=$DB->fetchAll($myquery);

      foreach ($results as $row) {
        $row["current"]="size";
        unset($row["pixfizzId"]);
        $final_arr[]=$row;
            }

    echo json_encode($final_arr);
}


    else if ($_POST["data_key"]=="size")
{   
    $final_arr;
    $fetcher =           $_POST["selected_id"];
    $fetcher_theme =     $_POST["themeid"];
    $fetcher_category=   $_POST["themecategory"];
    $fetcher_product=    $_POST["themeproduct"];
    $fetcher_cover =     $_POST["ctitle"];
    $fetcher_size =      $_POST["stitle"];

    $myquery="SELECT DISTINCT Size.stitle FROM Layout,Products,Occasion, Size, Theme 
    WHERE Layout.product=$fetcher_product
    AND Layout.occasion=$fetcher_category
    AND Layout.theme=$fetcher_theme 
    AND Layout.size=$fetcher_size
    AND Layout.size=Size.id";

    $results=$DB->fetchAll($myquery);

      foreach ($results as $row) {
        $row["current"]="finishing";
        unset($row["pixfizzId"]);
        $final_arr[]=$row;
            }

    echo json_encode($final_arr);
}

        else if ($_POST["data_key"]=="finishing")
{   
    $final_arr;
    $fetcher =           $_POST["selected_id"];
    $fetcher_theme =     $_POST["themeid"];
    $fetcher_category=   $_POST["themecategory"];
    $fetcher_product=    $_POST["themeproduct"];
    $fetcher_cover =     $_POST["ctitle"];
    $fetcher_size =      $_POST["stitle"];
    $fetcher_finishing = $_POST["ftitle"];

    $myquery="SELECT DISTINCT Finishing.ftitle FROM Layout,Products,Occasion, Size, Cover, finishing, Theme 
    WHERE Layout.product=$fetcher_product 
    AND Layout.occasion=$fetcher_category 
    AND Layout.theme=$fetcher_theme 
    AND Layout.size=$fetcher_size 
    AND Layout.cover=$fetcher_cover 
    AND Layout.finishing=$fetcher_finishing";

    $results=$DB->fetchAll($myquery);

      foreach ($results as $row) {
        $row["current"]="finishing";
        unset($row["pixfizzId"]);
        $final_arr[]=$row;
            }

    echo json_encode($final_arr);
}}
```

My Engine JS (what I assign):

```
         myItem.setId(jsonData[i].id);
         myItem.setImg(jsonData[i].image);
         myItem.setTitle(jsonData[i].title);
```

My Selects in JS (printing HTML):

```
myString +="<a>Sizes: </a><br><select id='sizesSelect' style=' width:200px'></select><br><br>";
    myString +="<a>Cover: </a><br><select id='coverSelect' style=' width:200px'><br></select><br><br>";
    myString +="<a>Finishing: </a><br><select id='finishingSelect' style=' width:200px'></select><br><br><br>";
```

Appending to Select in JS:

```
myString +="<script>$('#sizesSelect').append('<option val="+i+">"+this.getSize()+"</option>')</script>";
```

Now I need to know how can I post again to my PHP server to fetch the the values to other selects (refer for the img).[image]

Select Size -> Update Covers -> Select Covers -> Update Finishing -> Select Finishing

Comment: `$myquery="SELECT DISTINCT Layout.* FROM Layout,Products,Occasion, Cover, Theme 
    WHERE Layout.product=$fetcher_product 
    AND Layout.occasion=$fetcher_category 
    AND Layout.theme=$fetcher_theme 
    AND Layout.cover=$fetcher_cover;";` that is a string...

Comment: Consider moving to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I know how to type my query, I need the POST how to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SQL to store and present previous user choices, you could keep the previous choices as $_POST data by re-adding the choises to the HTML Form as hidden input fields. Example: `<input type="hidden" text="foo" name="<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['foo'])?>">`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have several recalls for the server everytime I'm fetching from the DB based on what the user chooses e.g. (Selected [USA] will fetch [New York, Washinton, Las Vegas, etc..]).